# Как выглядит поврежденный пакет данных

Tags: сеть, tcp, udp, сетевое-программирование, пакет

На всех форумах, на википедии, и в целом везде говорят: "UDP - протокол который не гарантирует целосную доставку пакета". Окей, я знаю что TCP переотправляет повреждённые пакеты, тем самым гарантирует его полную доставку. UDP же такого не делает и поэтому его называют ненадёжным. И вот у меня появился вопрос. Как выглядит повреждённый пакет данных. Типа, можно ли увидеть это повреждение как баг в текстовом ответе, или же какие то пиксели в отправляемой картинке изменит свой цвет, или любой другой баг, который свидетельствует про явно потеряный или повреждённый пакет, который можна увидеть, или, может, повреждение представляеться как-то иначе?

Comment: Повреждённый пакет до вас вообще не дойдёт, потому что будет отброшен по пути каким-нибудь роутером, проверяющим контрольную сумму

Comment: (теоретически пакет может побиться в сетевом кабеле межу вашим роутером и компьютером, но вероятность этого очень маленькая, и компьютер всё равно отбросит такой пакет, так что вы всё равно ничего не получите)